# How to convert uni code point value (utf16) to C char array

Tags: c, unicode, character-encoding

I have an api which takes uni code data as c character array and sends it as a correct sms in uni code.

Now i have four code point values corresponding to four characters in some native alphabet and i want to send those correctly by inserting them into a c char array.

I tried

```
char test_data[] = {"\x00\x6B\x00\x6A\x00\x63\x00\x69"};
```

where 0x006B is one code point and so on.

The api internally is calling

```
int len = mbstowcs(NULL,test_data,0);
```

which results in 0 for above. Seems like 0x00 is treated as a terminating null.

I want to assign the above code points correctly to c array so they result into corresponding utf16 characters on the receiving phone (which does support the char set). If required i have the leverage to change the api too.

Platform is Linux with glib

Comment: Looked at a lot of relevant existing questions, but couldn't exactly find the solution yet

Comment: Which encoding does the API expect? You're not stating that, and saying "takes unicode data as C character array" really doesn't tell much. You must know the expected encoding, or else there of course no way of knowing how to arrange the bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-16BE is not the native *execution (AKA multibyte) character set* and [`mbstowcs`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Non_002dreentrant-String-Conversion.html) does expect null-terminated strings, so this will not work. Since you are using Linux, the function is probably expecting any `char[]` sequence to be UTF-8.

I believe you can transcode character data in Linux using [uniconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/uniconv_002eh.html). I've only used the [ICU4C](http://site.icu-project.org/) project.

Your code would read the UTF-16BE data, transcode it to a common form (e.g. `uint8_t`), then transcode it to the native *execution character set* prior to calling the API (which will then transcode it to the native *wide character set*.)

*Note: this may be a lossy process if the execution character set does not contain the relevant code points, but you have no choice because this is what the API is expecting. But as I noted above, modern Linux systems should default to UTF-8. I wrote a little bit about transcoding codepoints in C [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html#I18N2010_CHAR_C).*

Comment: The questioner is using GLib, which has a fairly good selection of basic Unicode facilities: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html including transcoding.

Comment: Thanks i will explore them both

Comment: @ecatmur - thanks for pointing that out; the procedure will be the same regardless of the API used.

Comment: How do i perform this step? "then transcode it to the native execution character set prior to calling the API"... Prior to this i used g_utf16_to_utf8 () and obtained a utf8 string? Thanks

Comment: Okay i didn't have to do it actually. just usage of g_utf16_to_utf8() along with UTF16-LE worked for me. Thanks @McDowell and ecatmur

Answer (score 0):

I think using wchar_t would solve your problem.
Correct me if I am wrong or missing something.

Comment: wchar_t is just the wide character data type. I tried assigning this array to it. But the point is the api does not expect wchar_t. It takes plain c char array with one char per byte and converts it latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a union of chars and ints. 
`typedef union wchars{int int_arr[200]; char char_arr[800]};`
 memcpy the  data into this union for your assignment